# MSAccess SQL Too few parameters. Expected 4

Tags: sql, delphi, ms-access, anydac

I'm using Delphi XE2 and AnyDAC and an MSAccess db.

The table 'timea' has 5 fields:

> Rec_No   AutoNumber
>   App        text
>   User_ID  text
>   PW       text
>   Comment  memo

This code throws the error below. The query works just fine in Access query designer.

```
sql := 'INSERT INTO [timea] (App, User_ID, PW, Comment) VALUES ("zoo", "Bill", "mi7", "Liger");';
adconnection1.ExecSQL(sql);
```

Project PWB.exe raised exception class EMSAccessNativeException with message '[AnyDAC][Phys][ODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 4.'.

Comment: Have you tried using square brackets around column names?

Comment: Try single quotes instead of double quotes.

Comment: Single quotes should do the trick. I don't know about AnyDAC, but ADO (`TADOConnection`) allows also double quotes. in real code, use parameters.

Comment: @Frazz - No joy in brackets.

Comment: @Dan Bracuk - Single quoted didn't work, but doubled single quotes did. Who knew?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both SQL and Delphi are using single quotes as string boundaries. Since you want to have singe quote *inside* the string, you have to "escape" it using doube single quote.

For example, if you write `S := 'Guns''N''Roses'` the varieble `S` will contain string `Guns'N'Roses` - 12 characters, not 14.

Be careful when you are concatenating string values, since they might contain single quotes, too. The recommended way to write the query in this case is, for example:

```
sql := 'INSERT INTO Table (Col) VALUES (' + QuotedStr(Val) + ')';
```

Function `QuotedStr` wll take care and double all single quotes in the string. This is also essential to avoid insertion hacks.

Comment: In another program using DAO with Access, double quotes work just fine. The difference is a mystery.

Comment: Actually, depending on the driver used, different formats can be accepted. Some drivers accept, for example, different wildcards (`*`, `%`), date formats, etc.

Comment: Not quite true. Some DBMSs use double quotes, or different escape chars. Simply use parameters and you'll be fine. AnyDAC (FireDAC) will do the rest.